# Logic fault with nested loops pattern

Tags: java

I wrote a class to print a pattern:

```
1
2   4
3   5   7
4   6   8   10
5   7   9   11  13
```

I used this code:

```
public class pat3
{
    public void method()
    {
        int row;
        int val;

        for(row=1;row<=5;row++)
        {
            for(val=1;val<=row;val++)
            {
                System.out.print(val + 2 + "\t");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I have used two nested loops, the outer one controls rows in the pattern, and the inner one controls columns. Cross-referencing this with previous pattern problems, my logic seems okay.

However, I am getting an incorrect output when I run this class:

```
3   4   
3   4   5   
3   4   5   6   
3   4   5   6   7
```

I have tried changing the variables around and re-wording the `for` loops, but my output always varies randomly with no correlation, so I cannot find the cause of the problem. Can anybody help me out?

P.S. I'm new to coding, so no smart-alecky mathematical answers please, I'd just like a straightforward answer as to the problem in the code.

Comment: You can take a paper and see what are the values of val and row will be at each iteration. Then it will be easy to fix your mistake.

Comment: @ZouZou That was the first thing I tried, both with paper, and with my debugger, but I'm still not being able to locate the problem.

Comment: How do you expect to get ```1``` when you initialize your variables with 1 and in every output you add 2?

Comment: @vedantchandra Are you sure ? First you are doing `val + 2` with `val = 1` so it's normal you get 3. No magic here.

Comment: In your inner loop consider using `for(int add = 0; add < row; add += 2)`. I am sure you can handle the rest.

Comment: Ahh, I can't believe I missed that! Time to get some sleep I guess :-P Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Make the inner loop like this:

```
        for(val=0;val<row;val++)
        {
            System.out.print((row + 2*val) + "\t");
        }
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/yH32ap)

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your for loop:

```
for(int row=0;row<5;row++)
    {
        for(int val=0;val<=row;val++)
        {
            System.out.print(row+ 1 + val * 2 + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void method()
{
    int row;
    int val;

    for(row=1;row<=5;row++)
    {
        for(val=0;val<row; val++)
        {
            System.out.print((2*val) + row);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be even more helpful if you could add an explanation of why it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to the following one:

```
public void method()
{
    int row;
    int val;

    for(row=1;row<=5;row++)
    {
        for(val=1;val<=row;val++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", row + (val-1)*2);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output in console as follows:

```
 1 
 2  4 
 3  5  7 
 4  6  8 10 
 5  7  9 11 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal modification to your code:

```
System.out.print(row + (val - 1)*2 + "\t");
```